# How do I use the scope resolution operator for a nested class inside a template class?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template <typename T>
    class School{
     public:
    class Student{
     public:
     Student & operator++();
     Student operator++(int);
               
}
}
```

Assuming I have this in my header file, how would I use the scope resolution operator to for an hpp file? I have tried this but the result were an expected initializer before & token

```
template <class T>
T School<T> :: Student& Student:: operator++()
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

[One more, for the win](https://godbolt.org/z/Mxa3Ys) (with a pinch-hit from `typename`):

```
template <class T>
typename School<T>::Student &School<T>::Student::operator++()
{
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: tysm! It solved my problem. By the way, does it matter if I use T or typename there?

Comment: `template<typename T>` and `template<class T>` are interchangeable (in all but the most obscure situation). The consensus is that you should use `typename` as `T` can be any type including `int`. By using `class` you are implying that it can only be a class and that is not true.